# Мессенджер сообщений для Linux

Tags: linux

Может кто-нибудь подсказать мессенджер сообщений для Linux, чтоб там была возможность подключения mail.ru, icq, ВКонтакте и т.д.?

Answer (score 5):

[Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/) - для Gnome

[Kopete](http://kopete.kde.org/) - для KDE

Не знаю за mail.ru, но остальное точно понимают. Нужно просто смотреть по какому протоколу общается тот или иной сервис, и уже исходя из этого искать IM

Comment: Нет они не понимают майла

Comment: pidgin очень даже понимает mail.ru

Comment: с Pidgin у меня были некоторые проблемы с контакт листом. Один и тот же человек отображался два раза. Было некое дублирование.

Comment: G71, верятно пользователь находился в нескольких группах и отображение имен групп ыбло отключено. 
new_russian_man, если в списке доступных протоколов не написано mail.ru, то это не значит что это не работает, а товарищ mixerden сейчас расскажет как врубить маил :)

Comment: Если кому то интересно могу и рассказать)))

Answer (score 1):

Советую попробовать вот этот мессенжер http://www.instantbird.com/press-release-1.0.html